# Problems with including afxmt.h in VC++ 2010

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm getting exceptions when I include afxmt.h, I know it's not my code because I tested it with an empty project that only included that file.

It first throws a first-chance exception (mfc100ud.dll) and then it jumps to thrdcore.cpp AfxInitThread() and then goes to tidtable.c

Is there some project settings that I'm missing or some other stuff? I'm using VC++ 2010 Professional.

```
First-chance exception at 0x00b794ea (mfc100ud.dll) in Quick_Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
Unhandled exception at 0x77b815de in Quick_Test.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.
```

Stops at thrdcore.cpp line 405 and then in tidtable.c line 500.

EDIT:

Just tested this with a project that has precompiled headers and it worked. How would I make it work on my other projects, that were originally empty? Or should I just use a project with precompiled headers?

Comment: You ware doing MFC app right ?

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be that you are using release and trying to access the debug dll. Debug dlls usually ends with a "d" letter

Comment: It's all in debug. The use of MFC in the project settings is set to shared dll, so the error happens AFTER all the linker stuff. It's like it happens while including afxmt.h in the debug process.